# Accessing network responses in Cypress.io

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, cypress

I'm working on testing an OpenID Connect service, using Code and Implicit Flow. I would really like to be able to access the messages I get back from the service, especially the 303 See Other message which has the ID Token.

If someone can advise on how to get to response messages I would really appreciate it. Since the services exposes a HTML login page what happens is a 
cy.get("#loginButton").click() 
so I don't send a cy.request() and that is because I want to test login using the front-end.

Answer (score 8):

You should leverage [cy.route](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Without-Stubbing), how it works:

- before `cy.visit` you need to add `cy.server()`, it allows Cypress to intercept every request
- you add an alias to the login request

```js
cy.route({
  method: "POST",
  url: '/auth/token' // this is just an example, replace it with a part of the real URL called to log in the user
}).as("route_login"); // that's the alias, we'll use in soon
```

- right after the `cy.get("#loginButton").click()` command, you can `wait` for the login request to happen

```js
cy.wait("@route_login").then(xhr => {
  // you can read the full response from `xhr.response.body`
  cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body));
});
```

your final test should be something like

```js
it("Test description", () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.visit("YOUR_PAGE_URL");

  cy.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/auth/token'
  }).as("route_login");

  cy.get("#loginButton").click();

  cy.wait("@route_login").then(xhr => {
    // you can read the full response from `xhr.response.body`
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body));
  });

});
```

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: If you want to learn some more best practices about UI testing: I've just had a talk about the topic, [here the full slides](https://slides.com/noriste/milano-frontend-ui-testing-best-practices)

Comment: From what I can tell the issue is that the response is not an XHR response. The implicit code response comes with "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Could you share a minimal GitHub repo to play with, please?

Comment: typo: should be `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Not working with v4.0.2. Getting error `CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'doLogin'. No request ever occurred. `

Answer (score 4):

`cy.server()` and `cy.route()` are **deprecated** in Cypress 6.x

---

Use `cy.intercept()` instead:

```
cy.intercept('POST', '/organization', (req) => {
  expect(req.body).to.include('Acme Company')
})
```

Your tests can intercept, modify and wait on any type of HTTP request originating from your app.

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html (with examples)